# Name for historic style of mapping mountains as "mole mounds"?

Tags: terminology

I am referring to a graphic solution for depicting mountains in cartography that was popular I believe in years 1500s - 1700s.
Example from 1699: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/b1/New_Caledonia_in_Darien2.jpg/450px-New_Caledonia_in_Darien2.jpg

Anyone know how they are called?

Comment: US Chart 1, *Symbols, Abbreviations and Terms used on Paper and Electronic Navigational Charts*, calls this shading. It also lists "hachure" for hach line style. See page 20, Natural Features. https://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/publications/docs/us-chart-1/ChartNo1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is close, but still inaccurate. Hachure is a style used in shading those hills. But how are the hills called?

Comment: If there's no extant glossary in your specialist library how would it be a problem to use *mole mounds* - or better, English *molehills*, please?

Comment: No problem, I just wasn't sure if that was good enough. Is that a "Yes, it is good enough" ? Thanks for the reply